# Why does my loop execute once only? 

Tags: c++, while-loop

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;


int go_to(int x, int y)
{
  COORD c;
  c.X = x - 1;
  c.Y = y - 1;

  return  SetConsoleCursorPosition (GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), c);
}

void main(){
  int a=1;

  while(a<10){
    a++;
    cout<<"work"<<endl;
    go_to(3,6);
    cout<<"work"<<endl;
  }
}
```

I'm not understand why this loop work only 1 time, maybe you know where is problem ?
I thing that problem is in Cord, but don't know similar way to use CORD.

Comment: What are you trying to do? You are calling `go_to` nine times with the exact same parameters so it will always go to the same position.

Comment: Ok this is only example, but why loop work only 1 times ?

Comment: How are you determining it's only called once?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The variable a is only modified by the `a++;` line which increases its value by 1, and it isn't passed into `go_to(x,y)`, so it can't be affected by that function.

Your loop will definitely run for values a={1 to 9}, calling `go_to(3, 6)` each time, and also printing work twice.  I believe you're mistaken if you think otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

Your loop does the same thing on each iteration so you simply can't tell that it runs many (9) times.

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
while(a<10){ 
   a++; 
   cout<<"work"<<endl; 
   go_to(3,6); 
   cout<<"work"<<endl; 
}
```

To

```
while(a<10){ 
   a++; 
   cout<<"work"<<endl; 
   go_to(a,a*2); 
   cout<<"work"<<endl; 
}
```

And you'll see that it's actually running multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

The values for these are never changing.

```
while(a<10){
    a++;
    cout<<"work"<<endl;
    go_to(3,6);
    cout<<"work"<<endl;
  }
```

Instead of this, try something like this:

```
for(int a = 0; a < 10; a++{
        cout<<"work"<<endl;
        go_to(a + 3,a + 6);
        cout<<"work"<<endl;
      }
```

This way your values will actually change